# Tracking OSI packets with Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, packet, osi

All the 7 layers of the OSI model work together to define to the endpoint what is the type of machine he is dealing with.

But I wonder why can't I detect a OSI packet with an software like wireshark? Because Wireshark should track every packet that goes to my machine, right? But I've never seen an "OSI packet" before.

Am I doing something wrong? Is my concept of OSI packets right?

Comment: You can't detect an OSI packet with anything, because there aren't any. It is as dead as the dodo.

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark shows layers that are not exactly OSI or TCP/IP but a combination of both layers.

As Wireshark decodes packets at Data Link layer so we will not get physical layer information always. 
But in some cases, capturing adapter provides some physical layer information and can be displayed through Wireshark.
Generally, we see layers whick do not exceed below layers:

```
 - Physical Layer
 - Data Link Layer
 - Network Layer
 - Transport Layer
 - Application Layer
```

It should be noted that the layers is in reverse order different from OSI and TCP/IP model.
Refer to [link](https://linuxhint.com/osi_network_layer_analsysis_wireshark/) for more details.